# Ruby: get the max occurrences of many hashes depending their content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find-occurrences

I usually count the max occurrences of an array of items (int) like this:

```
specialties_with_frequency = specialties.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
@reference.specialty_id = specialties.max_by { |v| specialties_with_frequency[v] }
```

Today, I need to count the max occurrences of hashes content.

varietal is a database object containing these fields: 
*id, grape_id, percent*

My duplicate object can have multiple varietals.

```
@duplicates.each do |duplicate|
    duplicate.varietals.each do |varietal|
    end
end
```

For example, browsings duplicates, I will have:

```
duplicate 1: varietals => {grape_id => 1}, {grape_id => 2}
duplicate 2: varietals => {grape_id => 3}
duplicate 3: varietals => {grape_id => 1}, {grape_id => 2}
duplicate 4: varietals => {grape_id => 3}, {grape_id => 5}
```

In this case, the accepted data will be:

```
{grape_id => 1}, {grape_id => 2}
```

because there are 2 occurrences browsing all duplicates.

I have no idea of how to explore the same values in all occurrences.

Thanks,
Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the exact same code as before, only with varietals arrays as keys in your frequency hash. Just make sure the arrays are sorted so that the keys will be equal for the same content.

If the `grape_id` is the only field used for occurence checking, you can simplify a bit by mapping the array of varietals to an array of numbers, in which case your frequency builder will look like this:

```
specialties_with_frequency = @duplicates.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |h, duplicate|
  grape_ids = duplicate.varietals.map { |v| v[:grape_id] }.sort
  h[grape_ids] += 1; h
end
```

Given the example you provided, the value should now be:

```
{[1, 2]=>2, [3]=>1, [3, 5]=>1}
```

Comment: or use Set instead of Array. or use array of values instead of array of hashes containing always same single key.

Comment: Lars, thanks for the code. No need to use max_by on h object ? The result is already ordered from max to min occurrences ?

Comment: @alex.bour: the hash is not ordered, so you will still have to extract the maximum as before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Alex

Answer (score 0):

For arrays and hashes it’s better to use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
with_freq = whatever.group_by { |v| v } # (&:itself) for ruby2.3
                    .map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }
                    .to_h
```

If you need some sophisticated algorithm for grouping, change `{ |v| v }` to use this algorithm.